# Java 8 collectors groupBy and into a separate class

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of `Persons` which have some duplicate names.

```
class Person {
  String name;
}
```

I want to convert it to the list of `GroupedPersons` which contain the common name and the list of all Persons who have that name.

```
class GroupedPerson {
  String name;
  List<A> as;
}
```

Is it possible to do this with one collector and without any intermediate mapping or extra classes?

Comment: does `GroupedPerson` has both setters and getters? Or is it immutable?

Comment: Yes it does have all constructors/getter/setters as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose one way would be:

```
 persons
   .stream()          
   .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(
           Person::getName),
           map -> {
               return map.entrySet()
                         .stream()
                         .map(en -> new GroupedPerson(en.getKey(), en.getValue()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
}));
```

Or, you could use `toMap`:

```
persons  
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Person::getName,
            x -> {
                  List<Person> l = new ArrayList<>();
                  l.add(x);
                  return new GroupedPerson(x.getName(), l);
            },
            (left, right) -> {
                 left.getAs().addAll(right.getAs());
                 return left;
            }))
   .values();
```

Comment: This looks good but it would have to build a map and then we need to steam over that map. Is there another collector that could directly collect it to the object without creating a map first?

Comment: @danial how would imagine that? you still need a `Map` to group this

Comment: Yea it make sense I think this would be the optimal solution then.

Comment: @Danial, actually, you could use an AbstractList to make a lightweight view around the map if you use a map that guarantees iteration order

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Here is a way to do it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GroupedStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<GroupedPerson> groupedPersons = Arrays.asList("john harry john harry sam jordon bill steve bill".split(" "))
            .stream()
            .map(name -> new Person(name))
            .map(person -> new Object[] {person.name, new ArrayList<>()})
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(tuple-> (String) tuple[0], tuple -> (List<Person>) tuple[1] ))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> new GroupedPerson(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    static class Person {
        public final String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    static class GroupedPerson {

        public final String name;
        public final List<Person> person;

        public GroupedPerson(String name, List<Person> person) {
            this.name = name;
            this.person = person;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you modify your `GroupedPerson` model to be something along the lines of:

```
public class GroupedPerson {
    private String name;
    private List<Person> people;

    public GroupedPerson(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        people = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addPeople(List<Person> people) {
        this.people.addAll(people);
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person){
           people.add(person);
    }

    public List<Person> getPeople(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(people);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    
}
```

Then you can have a `Collection` of `GroupedPerson` objects with the names and all the corresponding people with that specific name like this:

```
Collection<GroupedPerson> resultSet = peopleList
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName,
                        p -> {
                            GroupedPerson groupedPerson = new GroupedPerson(p.getName());
                            groupedPerson.addPerson(p);
                            return groupedPerson;
                        },
                        (p, p1) -> {
                            p.addPeople(p1.getPeople());
                            return p;
                        }
                )).values();
```

if for some reason you don't want the receiver type to be `Collection<T>` then you can convert to a specific collection type if deemed appropriate by simply doing.

```
List<GroupedPerson> result = new ArrayList<>(resultSet);
```